# Working with friends on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to start working on a project with a friend on GitHub. We both have the GitHub apps, GitHub accounts and a repository setup with the starting files for the projects.

Problem is, when we are working on the project and each one is doing a different thing we start getting errors when trying to sync and commit files to the repo. How should this be done?

**PS**

Also, when committing files to a repo that only I am using, I get this error from my GitHub client:

```
    # On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   bin/classes/fourtytwo/studios/rednet/Course.class
#   modified:   src/fourtytwo/studios/rednet/Course.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 (256)
```

Comment: This question is way too broad. You basically need to learn git. Read Pro Git. It's freely available.

Comment: Always pull before you push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like JB Nizet commented, you should learn about using git, http://learn.github.com is a good resource.

And even once you've learned more about git, knowing how to use git depends largely on your use case, there are several models, [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) being one of the most popular ones. The right model depends on how many people you work with, how closely related the work is, deployment strategies, and many more variables and preferences.

For the particular problem you are mentioning, going with two separate topic branches to work on might be the right option, and merging back to an integration branch, such as `master` or `develop`, once each branch is ready.

Now, if the work you and your friend are doing is very tightly related and can't/shouldn't be divided into smaller work units (i.e. *irreducible complexity*), you might want to work on the same branch and work closely as a unit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, learn git.

There are multiple resources available where you can learn about git:

- http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html
- http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1
- http://gitready.com
- http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git

After that, if you are new to git, you should consider using a model that fits your workflow.
One example of a successful branching model is GitFlow. You can read more about gitflow here:

- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Reading those articles would help you a lot on getting started.

Answer (score 0):

You should start using branches. Each of you one branch.